# Can't work with findViewById

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I'm having problem with `findViewById()`. Whenever i use this in this code it shows me error. Sometimes Android studio suggest me to do like this `TextView DateView = null;` and

```
DateView = (TextView)DateView.findViewById(R.id.DateView);
```

but that gives also a error. Can someone help me to work out with this code.

```
public class OperationFragment extends Fragment {


    public OperationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_operation, container, false);
    }

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstabceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstabceState);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        String formattedDate = dd.format(c.getTime());
        String formattedTime = dt.format(c.getTime());
        TextView DateView;
        TextView TimeView;
        System.out.println(formattedTime);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
        DateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DateView);
        DateView.setText(formattedDate);
        TimeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TimeView);
        TimeView.setText(formattedTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to get access to your views in onCreateView()

Answer (score 2):

As you are working with fragment I suggest to do it this way :

Inside onCreateView :

```
TextView TimeView;
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_operation, container, false);

TimeView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TimeView);
TimeView.setText("Anik Rahman");
return rootView;
```

Comment: No.That's also don't work for me. It gives me several errors.

Comment: @AnikRahman Did you remove everything from onCreate as it is called before onCreateView ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

The first and most important one is, that `onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()` for [Fragements](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Instead use [`onViewCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

The second one is, that there is no method `findViewById()` on fragments. In `onViewCreated()` you have a `View` parameter though. So there you can just use `view.findViewById()` instead.